# SQL Server non-clustered index is not being used

Tags: sql-server, indexing, query-optimization

An application (*the underlying code of which can't be modified*) is running a select statement against a relatively large table (~1.8M rows, 2GB) and creating a huge performance bottleneck on the DB server.

The table itself has approx. 120 columns of varying datatype.  The select statement is selecting about 100 of those columns based on values of 2 columns which have both been indexed individually and together.

e.g.

```
SELECT  
    column1, 
    column2,
    column3,
    column4,
    column5, 
    and so on.....
FROM
    ITINDETAIL 
WHERE 
    (column23 = 1 AND column96 = 1463522)
```

However, SQL Server chooses to ignore the index and instead scans the clustered (PK) index which takes forever (this was cancelled after 42 seconds, it's been known to take over 8 minutes on a busy production DB).

[image]

If I simply change the select statement, replacing all columns with just a `select count(*)` , the index is used and results return in milliseconds.

[image]

**EDIT**: I believe `ITINDETAIL_004` (where column23 and column96 have been indexed together) is the index that should be getting used for the original statement.

Confusingly, if I create a non-clustered index on the table for the two columns in the where clause like this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ITINDETAIL20220504] 
ON [ITINDETAIL] ([column23] ASC, [column96] ASC)
INCLUDE (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5,  
         and so on..... )
```

and include *ALL* other columns from the select statement in the index (in my mind, this is essentially just creating a TABLE!), then run the original select statement, the new HUGE index is used and results are returned very quickly:

[image]

However, I'm not sure this is the right way to address the problem.

How can I force SQL Server to use what I think is the correct index?

Version is: SQL Server 2017

Comment: What index is it you think is the correct one then, if not the index `ITINDETAIL20220504`?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified in my post - I believe ITINDETAIL_004 (where column23 and column96 have been indexed together) is the index that should be getting used for the statement

Comment: Does that index `INCLUDE` any of the columns like the index `ITINDETAIL20220504` does? If not, then that index will *not* be a covering index, and thus SQL Server is determining that a scan of the clustered index (which is covering) is faster than a possible seek on the other, followed by a key lookup (which can be expensive).

Comment: *"How can I force SQL server to use what I think is the correct index?"* In truth, rarely is the index *you* think is the correct is the correct index if SQL Server thinks otherwise. Despite what some believe, SQL Server is very good at making informed choices about what index(es) it should be using, provided your statistics are up to date, and the cached plan isn't based on old and out of date information.

Comment: The `ITINDETAIL_004` index doesn't `INCLUDE` any columns - `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ITINDETAIL_004] ON [ITINDETAIL]
(
 [colum23] ASC,
 [column96] ASC
)`     
If I try and include those columns in a new index, I get the error `Cannot use duplicate column names in index.`

Comment: You don't `INCLUDE` columns from the sorting columns of the `INDEX`, `INCLUDE` is for other columns (that aren't going to be part of the sorting). Exactly like you showed for your index `ITINDETAIL20220504`. It seems that the index `ITINDETAIL20220504 ` is *exactly* the index you need. As I assumed, your other index (`ITINDETAIL_004`) doesn't `INCLUDE` any of the column you have in the `SELECT`, so it's not covering. As a result SQL Server has determined that a seek on that index, followed by a key lookup on the clustered index is more expensive (that a CI scan), and so isn't doing it.

Comment: So would you suggest that the index I've created which `INCLUDES` `all` the other columns in the select statement is the correct way to address this issue?

Comment: Yes, I would (and did) suggest that. The alternative would be the reevaluate your design, and reduce the number of columns in your table; splitting it into many tables. Then you don't need `INDEX`es with such a large number of columns in the `INCLUDE`.

Comment: Thank you Larnu, unfortunately a redesign isn't an option in this scenario - I'm very limited in what I can do with it.  If you want to craft your response into an answer I'll mark it as one.

Comment: There's one important fact that you didn't mention. How many rows does your query select? Because a nonclustered index is only useful if a small percentage of all rows is selected. If it does select only a small percentage, then make sure the statistics of the index are up to date. When in doubt run sp_updatestats

Comment: Perhaps a filtered covering index might be worthwhile, as it doesn't recreate *all* the data

Comment: @Gert-Jan, precisely zero - there are no rows that match the criteria so nothing is returned, all records in "column96" are NULL

Comment: @Huskie69 and how many rows are there for column23 = 1 ?
Because the statistics about the leading column of a compound index are great. But I wouldn't be surprised if the selectivity of the remaining column is mostly based on heuristics. And since the selectivity of column96 is as bad as it can be (since there's only one unique value), the optimizer might assume a number like 33% or 66%

Comment: @Gert-Jan - there are nearly 1.8 Million rows, all with the same value of 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on additional details from the comments, it appears that the index you want SQL Server to use isn't a covering index; this means that the index doesn't contain all the columns that are referenced in the query. As such, if SQL Server were to use said index, then it would need to first do a seek on the index, and then perform a key lookup on the clustered index to get the full details of the row. Such lookups can be expensive.

As a result of the index you want not being covering, SQL Server has determined that the index you want it to to use would produce an inferior query plan to simply scanning the entire clustered index; which is by definition covering as it `INCLUDE`s all other columns not in the `CLUSTERED INDEX`.

For your index `ITINDETAIL20220504` you have `INCLUDE`d all the columns that are in your `SELECT`, which means that it is covering. This means that SQL Server can perform a seek on the index, and get all the information it needs from that seek; which is far less costly that a seek followed by a key lookup and quicker than a scan of the entire clustered index. This is why this information works.

---

We coould put this into some kind of analogy using a Library type scenario, which is full of Books, to help explain this idea more:

Let's say that the Clustered Index is a list of *every* book in the library sorted by it's ISBN number (The Primary Key). Along side that ISBN number you have the details of the Author, Title, Publication Date, Publisher, If it's hardcover or softcover, the colour of the spine, the section of the Library the Book is located in, the book case, and the shelf.

Now let's say you want to obtain any books by the the Author Brandon Sanderson published on or after 2015-01-01. If you then wanted to you *could* go through the entire list, one by one, finding the books by that author, checking the publication date, and then writing down it's location so you can go and visit each of those locations and collect the book. This is effectively a Clustered Index Scan.

Now let's say you have a list of all the books in the Library again. The list contains the Author, Publication Date, and the ISBN (The Primary Key), and is ordered by the Author and the Publication Date. You want to fulfil the same task; obtain any books by the the Author Brandon Sanderson published on or after 2015-01-01. Now you can easily go through that list and find all those books, but you don't know where they are. As a result even after you have gone straight to the Brandon Sanderson "section" of the list, you'll still need to write all the ISBNs down, and then find each of those ISBN in the original list, get their location and title. This is your index `ITINDETAIL_004`; you can easily find the rows you want to filter to, but you don't have all the information so you have to go somewhere else afterwards.

Lastly we have a 3rd list, this list is ordered by the author and then publication date (like the 2nd list), but also includes the Title, the section of the Library the Book is located in, the book case, and the shelf, as well as the ISBN (Primary key). This list is *ideal* for your task; it's in the right order, as you can easily go to Brandon Sanderson and then the first book published on or after 2015-01-01, *and* it has the title and location of the book. *This* is your `INDEX` `ITINDETAIL20220504` would be; it has the information in the order you want, and contains *all* the information you asked for.

---

Saying all this, you *can* force SQL Server to choose the index, but as I said in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72111522/sql-server-non-clustered-index-is-not-being-used/72112227#comment127414753_72111522):

> In truth, rarely is the index *you* think is the correct is the correct index if SQL Server thinks otherwise. Despite what some believe, SQL Server is very good at making informed choices about what index(es) it should be using, provided your statistics are up to date, and the cached plan isn't based on old and out of date information.

Let's, however, demonstrate what happens if you do with a simple set up:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
                            SomeGuid uniqueidentifier DEFAULT NEWID(),
                            SomeDate date)
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (SomeDate)
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,T.I,'19000101')
FROM dbo.Tally(100000,0) T;
```

Now we have a table with 100001 rows, with a Primary Key on `ID`. Now let's do a query which is an overly simplified version of yours:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       SomeGuid
FROM dbo.SomeTable
WHERE SomeDate > '20220504';
```

No surprise, this results in an Clsutered Index Scan:
[image: Query Plan showing Index Scan of Clustered Primary Key]

Ok, let's add an index on `SomeDate` and run the query again:

```sql
CREATE INDEX IX_NonCoveringIndex ON dbo.SomeTable (SomeDate);
GO
--Index Scan of Clustered index
SELECT ID,
       SomeGuid
FROM dbo.SomeTable
WHERE SomeDate > '20220504';
```

Same result, and SSMS has even suggested an index:
[image: Query Plan showing Index Scan of Clustered Primary Key, and a suggested index, which "coincidentally" we'll be creating.]

Now, as I mentioned, you *can* force SQL Server to use a specific index. Let's do that and see what happens:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       SomeGuid
FROM dbo.SomeTable WITH (INDEX(IX_NonCoveringIndex))
WHERE SomeDate > '20220504';
```

And this gives exactly the plan I suggested; A key lookup:
[image: Query Plan showing Index Seek of created index, and then a key lookup on the Clustered Index]

This is *expensive*. In fact, if we turn on the statistics for IO and Time, the query without the index hint took 40ms, the one with the hint took **107**ms in the first run. Subsequent runs all had the second query taking around *double* the time of the first. IO wise the first query has a simple scan and 398 logical reads; the latter had **5** scans and ***114403*** logical reads!

Now, finally, let's add that covering Index and run:

```sql
CREATE INDEX IX_CoveringIndex ON dbo.SomeTable (SomeDate) INCLUDE (SomeGuid);
GO

SELECT ID,
       SomeGuid
FROM dbo.SomeTable
WHERE SomeDate > '20220504';
```

Here we can see that seek we wanted:
[image: Query Plan showing Index Seek of created covering index index]

If we look at the IO and times again compared to the prior 2, we get 1 scan, 202 logical reads, and it was running in about 25ms.

Comment: Strangely, a colleague of mine picked up on this in my absense today - he created a new index (which was identicial to `ITINDETAIL_004` which he wasn't aware existsed).  From that point on, the optimiser has been using the original `ITINDETAIL_004`.
Keep in mind that I'd rebuilt all indexes on this table beforehand and gathered stats etc.  This almost seems like a SQL Server bug

Comment: Perhaps SQL Server was using a cached plan, @Huskie69 . I would not suggest it is a bug; that is very unlikely. If you can consistently produce such behaviour then report it as a bug, but you need to ensure you can consistently reproduce it, and are using the latest version of a **fully supported** version of SQL Server.